# Is there a way to vectorize this loop?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I'm trying to simulate the results of two different dice. One die is fair (i.e. the probability of each number is 1/6), but the other isn't.

I have a numpy array with 0's and 1's saying which die is used every time, 0 being the fair one and 1 the other. I'd like to compute another numpy array with the results. In order to do this task, I have used the following code:

```
def dice_simulator(dices : np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
  n = len(dices)
  results = np.zeros(n)
  i = 0
  for dice in np.nditer(dices):
    if dice:
      results[i] = rnd.choice(6, p = [1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4]) + 1
    else:
      results[i] = rnd.choice(6) + 1
    i += 1
  return results
```

This takes a lot of time compared to the rest of the program, and think it is because I'm iterating over a numpy array instead of using vectorization of operations. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct way to do it.

```py
def dice_simulator(dices: np.array) -> np.array:
    return np.where(
        dices,
        rnd.choice(6, dices.shape, p = [1/12, 1/12, 1/12, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4]),
        rnd.choice(6, dices.shape)
    ) + 1
```

**Edit:** as noted by the other answers this answer generates both random arrays at full size which may be wasteful, one method you can avoid any overgenerating is based on **@Claudio** answer but with zero overgeneration is as following.

```py
def dice_simulator_slices_improved(dices):
    if dices.dtype != bool:
        dices = dices.astype(bool) # because we will iterate over it 3 times.
    N = dices.shape[0]
    n_Ones  = np.count_nonzero(dices)
    n_zeros = N - n_Ones
    results = np.empty(dices.shape[0],dtype=float) # reserve output array
    results[np.logical_not(dices)] = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6], size=n_zeros)
    results[dices] = np.random.choice(
        [1,2,3,4,5,6], size=n_Ones, p=[1/12,1/12,1/12,1/4,1/4,1/4])
    return results
```

this is typically the fastest way to do it with zero overgeneration, now the difference between np.where and this non-overgenerating method depends on both arrays used in filling it, if their calculation is trivial, like inserting 0 and 1, then np.where is almost 5 times faster, because it only iterates over `dices` once, but if the generation is as expensive as `np.random.choice` with `p` parameter, which happens to be very expensive, then no overgeneration is the way to go.

Comment: @Claudio, acutally `random.choice` with a certain p is very slow, it's the bottleneck in this, and your answer reduces the number of entries in it to almost half, hence it produces faster code overall, althought your forgot the `+1` at the end, but it doesn't affect the final results, it only exaggerates the difference, althought you are also over-generating the first random array, but its generation is fast anyway, and a faster answer has to be implemented in C++.

Comment: @Claudio in a case where generating both arrays was faster, and the bottleneck was in the actual mixing mechanism, you'd find np.where to be the faster choice since it only iterates over memory once, where you had to iterate over memory 4-5 times. (or in case the memory access was slower compared to the calculations done), for example if you replace the random calculation with just putting 0 and 1, you'd end up with np.where being 5 times faster.

Comment: @Claudio i have editted my answer with a faster version of your non-overgenerating algorithm, its faster for many reasons, but changing `np.empty` to `np.zeros` has no impact, which is the price of iterating once on an array.

Answer (score 1):

Answers already given vectorize by over generating and throwing up some outputs, it seems wrong.

Moreover, I will generalize to any number of dices.

First, you need to be able to get a `condlist`: it is a list of length the number of dices, with each i-th element being a boolean array containing `True` where the i-th dice should be used:

```py
dices_idxs = np.array([0, 1, 2])
dices_sequence = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0])

condlist = np.equal(*np.broadcast_arrays(dices_sequence[None, :], dices_idxs[:, None]))

print(condlist)

# [[ True False False False False False  True]
#  [False  True False False  True  True False]
#  [False False  True  True False False False]]
```

Second, you can generalize the answer given by @Ahmed AEK using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
def dice_simulator_select(dices_sequence, dices_weights):
    faces = np.arange(1, 7)
    num_dices = len(dices_weights)
    dices_idxs = np.arange(num_dices)
    num_throws = len(dices_sequence)

    condlist = list(
        np.equal(*np.broadcast_arrays(dices_sequence[None, :], dices_idxs[:, None]))
    )
    choicelist = [
        RNG.choice(faces, size=num_throws, p=dices_weights[dice_idx])
        for dice_idx in range(num_dices)
    ]
    return np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

But it has the issue stated first as it over-generates then discards some generated values, which can be problematic considering randomness.

A more correct way is to use [`np.piecewise`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html):

```py
def dice_simulator_piecewise(dices_sequence, dices_weights):
    faces = np.arange(1, 7)
    num_dices = len(dices_weights)
    dices_idxs = np.arange(num_dices)
    num_dices = len(dices_weights)

    condlist = list(
        np.equal(*np.broadcast_arrays(dices_sequence[None, :], dices_idxs[:, None]))
    )
    # note size=len(x) ensure no more sample than needed are generated
    funclist = [
        lambda x: RNG.choice(faces, size=len(x), p=dices_weights[int(x[0])])
    ] * num_dices


    return np.piecewise(dices_sequence, condlist, funclist)
```

You can use the functions as follows, and see that the correct function using `np.piecewise` is even faster (20% faster in below case):

```py
RNG = np.random.default_rng()

dices_weights = [
    None,  # uniform
    [1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4],
    None,
    [1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 12],
    None,
    [1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4],
]
num_dices = len(dices_weights)
num_throws = 1_000
dices_sequence = RNG.choice(np.arange(num_dices), size=num_throws)


%timeit dice_simulator_select(dices_sequence, dices_weights)
%timeit dice_simulator_piecewise(dices_sequence, dices_weights)

# 311 µs ± 5.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# 240 µs ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is **the fastest way** and because speed matters (this was the issue leading to the question) therefore also **so far the best solution**:

```
def dice_simulator_slices(dices):
    results  = RNG.integers(1,high=6,endpoint=True,size=dices.shape[0])
    results[dices==1] = RNG.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6], 
        size=get_size(dices), p=[1/12,1/12,1/12,1/4,1/4,1/4])
    return results
```

Here the required imports for the function above:

```
import numpy as np
RNG = np.random.default_rng()
get_size = np.count_nonzero
```

Now let's compare the timings of the other solutions to this above:

```
dice_simulator_piecewise  SIZE = 100_000_000 : 5.483888
dice_simulator_add_arrays SIZE = 100_000_000 : 5.148283
dice_simulator_np_where   SIZE = 100_000_000 : 4.838409
dice_simulator_slices_gen SIZE = 100_000_000 : 3.437379
dice_simulator_slices     SIZE = 100_000_000 : 2.976977
```

Maybe surprizing in the above results is that by optimizing by not
over generating slows things down, so *over generating need not
to be wrong*.

The current state of my own knowledge is that *(as stated by Ahmed AEK
in his answer)* the calculation of random choices in case a weight is
not None *(notice that in numpy the weight parameter is called 'p', not
'weight')* is the main speed bottleneck.

---

A bit slower, but still faster than other proposed solutions (see the
timings above) is my 'generic slice' solution supporting any number of
dices like the 'piecewise' solution does:

```
def dice_simulator_slices_gen(arr_dice_nums, arr_dice_num_weight):
    faces = np.arange(1, 7)
    results = np.empty(arr_dice_nums.shape[0], dtype=np.int8)
    for dice_num, weight in enumerate(arr_dice_num_weight): 
        bln_slice = arr_dice_nums == dice_num
        no_throws = np.count_nonzero(bln_slice)
        if weight is None: 
            results[bln_slice]=RNG.integers(1,high=6,endpoint=True,size=no_throws)
        else: 
            results[bln_slice]=RNG.choice(faces,p=weight,size=no_throws)
    return results
```

Comment: [My solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816340/51685) seems to be faster still.

Comment: @AKX :yes, if you improve it by taking a random section out of the pre-calculated tables you will achieve a 5x times better performance and if you improve it by pre-calculating tables for narrow ranges of 0 to 1 ratios in dices your approach will achieve a far over 1000x times better performance.

Comment: So... You'd agree this is no longer the fastest solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def dice_simulator(dices):
    p = [1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4]
    size = dices.shape
    fair_die = np.random.choice(6, size=size)
    unfair_die = np.random.choice(6, p=p, size=size)
    return (dices == 0) * fair_die + (dices == 1) * unfair_die + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could do the heavy lifting in advance, and just choose from that table of rolls afterwards. You can increase `lut_size` if you feel like it, but I doubt it would actually matter as far as accuracy goes.

```
lut_size = 65535
fair_dice_table = rng.integers(1, 6, endpoint=True, size=(lut_size,))
nonfair_dice_table = rng.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], size=(lut_size,), p=[1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 12, 1 / 4, 1 / 4, 1 / 4])


def dice_simulator_lookup(dices):
    indices = rng.integers(0, high=lut_size, size=dices.shape[0])
    return np.where(dices == 0, fair_dice_table[indices], nonfair_dice_table[indices])
```

This seems to outperform some of the other solutions here by about 1.4x to 1.7x.

Comment: *Are you serious with comparison of speed performance to other solutions here or is it just a joke?* And why bother at all with calculation of `indices` instead of just taking a random section with `dices.shape` out of a larger pre-calculated tables? This will make `np.where` according to *Ahmed AEK*s answer 5x times faster as any other solution here. And why not pre-calculate tables for ranges of 0s to 1s ratios in dices to convert it to an lookup in an already im memory existing table making it 1000 times faster?

Comment: @Claudio Yes, I'm serious. This is a nice memory-runtime tradeoff with the same randomness properties than the other solutions.

Comment: @Claudio Anyway, can you tell me what size of a precalculated table would then work for _any_ size of `dices`? Or how you'd map an arbitrary `dices` to these ratios-of-dices?

Comment: You are assuming that the `dice_simulator_lookup()` function will be run often enough within same script to compensate the time lost due to the pre-calculation, right? The question is how many times it must be run to become actually *faster*? For a one-time run it is slower than any other solution here especially for small sizes of `dices`. Generally it seems that pre-calculation doesn't give any speed advantage as calculation is in most cases faster than reading/loading pre-calculated values.

Comment: *Can you tell me what size of a pre-calculated table would then work for any size of dices?* I can't, because it will lead to an endless and pointless discussion about randomity as such. Generally my current personal point of view is that any pre-calculated or pre-defined values can't be afterwards considered to be random, so pre-calculation is not the way to go for randomity, anyway. And yes, I am aware of the fact that the random modules used in the solutions are a kind of pre-defined table-lookup ...

Comment: If you came up with an own random generator much faster than these implemented in Python or numpy ... why not? But you use them for pre-calculation and I can't see what should be the real advantage of doing that? If it were ... update numpy with your idea to make its random functions 1.5x times faster. If dices are using every time another weights ... your approach slows things down. With any finite size of values you will get an in a long run a detectable bias ...

Comment: @Claudio "The question is how many times it must be run to become actually faster?" I ran some tests, and it seems "about 200 times with n_dice = 100", "about 100 times with n_dice = 1000", "about 20 times with n_dice = 10000", "about 2 times with n_dice = 100000", and for a million dice (and probably up) this seems faster in all cases.

Comment: For a million dices sequence ... you need a million sized pre-calculated table. No way with a small table pretending randomity reusing a by scrambling only the order of its entries.

Comment: @Claudio You are right in that 65k entries may bias a large enough number of trials, but with a 262k entry table, the distributions look like https://i.imgur.com/5pqvMRX.png which seems pretty good to me.

Comment: A question: Let's assume 60 throws with a fair dice. 10 x 1, 10 x 2,...,10 x 6 one after each other in a row so there is a series of ten ones after each other and so on. How do you calculate the *'distribution'* in such case? Another question: are all the lines in the diagram exactly the same, so only the last color can be seen?

Comment: @Claudio (1) Sorry, I didn't label the chart correctly. The X axis is the dice pip (1..6), the Y axis is the number of observations of that pip. Your scenario would yield a straight line at Y=10. (2) No, they're not exactly the same (if you zoom in, you can see a bit of green at X=4); not even the "more perfect" random generators yield exactly the same results at this many trials (that's randomness for you).